# Cannot add sqlite3 to a project using npm on Debian WSL

Tags: sqlite, npm, debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux, node-sqlite3

Recently I have switched from developing on bare Windows to WSL Debian. I tried to install sqlite3 in in my project using `npm i sqlite3` but it results in an error. I have the latest versions of Debian, Node, npm, and sqlite3 installed. I have tried to install the same package on Windows and it worked fine. It also seems to just be the issue with sqlite3 package because I could install express without any issues. The error message:

```
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@1.1.2: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path \\wsl.localhost\Debian\home\fukari\todo-app\node_modules\sqlite3
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! '\\wsl.localhost\Debian\home\fukari\todo-app\node_modules\sqlite3'
npm ERR! CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
npm ERR! UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
npm ERR! 'node-pre-gyp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
npm ERR! operable program or batch file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP Omen\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-25T21_25_18_324Z-debug-0.log
fukari@DESKTOP-J0MVS5V:~/todo-app$ npm i sqlite3
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@1.1.2: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path \\wsl.localhost\Debian\home\fukari\todo-app\node_modules\sqlite3
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! '\\wsl.localhost\Debian\home\fukari\todo-app\node_modules\sqlite3'
npm ERR! CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
npm ERR! UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
npm ERR! 'node-pre-gyp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
npm ERR! operable program or batch file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP Omen\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-25T21_26_10_895Z-debug-0.log
```